# Phusion Passenger without RVM

Tags: phusion-passenger, rubygems

Usually I use RVM + Passenger for my rails applications. Recently, however, I needed to use Passenger without RVM. And I'm confused about gem location.

What's the location of gems that Passenger without RVM uses? The system gems or what?

If I do 'bundle install', gems are installed for the user, right? Then, the gems are not used by Passenger.

Can you help me with this confusion?

Answer (score 1):

Procedure differs with the base OS installed but basically are the same.

Please consult this

[How to set-up Ruby on Rails server on a Linux cloud (Ubuntu 10.04 LTS)](http://techinspiration.wordpress.com/2011/11/26/how-to-set-up-ruby-on-rails-server-with-mysql-and-passanger-on-a-linux/)

Comment: It's very helpful. I learned a lot from it. Thanks.